# ActiveRecord where at least x records of association exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's say users have comments and I want all users with three comments or more.

`User.joins(:comments)` will get me any user that has 
one or more comments. What is the nicest way to get Users with at least three comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nicer way might be to write that subquery using the API:

```
subquery = Comment.select("user_id").
                   group(:user_id).
                   having("COUNT(*) >= 3").to_sql
User.where("id IN (#{subquery})")
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL like this:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE user_id = users.id GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3)
```

Which in ActiveRecord notation translates to:

```
User.where('EXISTS (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE user_id = users.id GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3)')
```